# Is there a way to dynamically get URL as a path to plugin root, not a local path?

Tags: plugins, plugins-url

Is there a way to get path to the root plugin folder as a remote URL instead of a local path.
For Example:
Instead of: `c:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my_plugin\`
I want to get: `localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/`

Is there a way to get the 'web' path instead of local one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) and [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) functions.